# Rename file name before uploading to PHP server

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I wonder if it is possible to change file name and attributes of

```
 <input type="file" id="image">
```

with Javascript or Jquery before uploading using PHP?

I have found that it is possible to rename it on back-end with PHP but I want to have name changed to say Date().getTime() before uploading. On server I would simply move file to location.

Comment: no, you cannot change the name before uploading. If you are letting users upload files there is no way you would want javascript to be able to access and modify their filesystem

Comment: so where is your uploading part ??

Comment: i see, but how would you handle lets say you allow them to upload file and rename on server but return/show new filename and file from server?

Comment: The browser need to know the filename as it is on the users disc, otherwise it wont be able to find it when it sends the data to the server. Do your renaming on the server anyway as you need to also check that you are not overwriting another file with the same name when you are on the server

Comment: why not make that change on back-end?

Comment: Anyone tried Plupload, maybe this works?

Comment: You can use the [File](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/#dfn-file) constructor to rebuild your file with a new name and upload it with XHR2(YMMV). Of course you could just rename it on the server, if you want the name to come from the client just pass it as another field.